# How to efficiently Update table created from existing tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-update

I recently created a table in SQL consisting of columns from multiple existing tables. It is a rather large and complex table consisting of financial information for companies/securities over the last 20 years. I need to update the data everyday with the most recent data from the previous day but am running into problems with the amount of time it takes to do this with my current approach. My current approach (which i know isnt the most efficient as i am new to SQL) is to drop and recreate the table everyday to show updated records. I believe the main reason for the time issues is that the table is running through all twenty years of data for each column and row. I have been researching and attempting Update statements but havent found anything that works yet.What would be an efficient way to update the table to only add the most recent data?

Comment: Why are you creating this table at all?  Why not just run a query for whatever data you desire from the "multiple existing tables" as/when needed?

Comment: With no details you aren't going to get much of an answer. The idea of a separate table to hold summary information is a losing battle. Get this data when you need it with a stored proc or a view.

Comment: @SeanLange  Sorry about lack of detail, did not want the question to be too long. I am analyzing the data in R using the package ROracle.

Comment: @eggyal We tried sending the query directly from R using ROracle however it would time out. So instead we tested pulling in an entire table of comparable size and it returned the table very quickly. So as a hack we decided to create a table in the DB and just pull in the table to R. Alternately we explored printing the output to a flat file (e.g., CSV file) but ran into formatting issues.

Comment: Do you need to pull the entire 20 years of data from the database every time you want to look at something there? I'd think you'd only need to have all the data *available* to you but when you want to see something, you usually want a specific piece of information, not the entire lot. So, it is still not very clear why it must be a separate table and not, for instance, a view.

Comment: So your real problem is that the original query was timing out.  Perhaps post a question on that?  May simply be that you need to tweak your indexes.